# "I've been working here since two months ago"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, present-perfect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proper usage of “since” and “from” with regard to duration of time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/proper-usage-of-since-and-from-with-regard-to-duration-of-time)
>   [Is “since I’m” now an acceptable alternative to “since I was”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40759/is-since-im-now-an-acceptable-alternative-to-since-i-was)

With the Present Perfect (Progressive) "since" can be used when a reference point is indicated, e.g.:

> I've been working here since last month.

Can I use "since 2 months ago" as a reference point, as in:

> I've been working here since two months ago.

Comment: Also related: [Since more than six months](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/83958/2303) and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1358/2303).

Comment: Oh...the actual duplicate seems to be your second link.

Answer (score 5):

You can, but it’s not advisable. *Since* has to have a specific time reference. *Two months ago* is such a reference, but a reader might initially be confused by seeing *since* followed by *two months*, which would normally be preceded by *for*.  Better to write either *I`ve been working here for two months* or *I started working here two months ago.*

Answer (score 2):

You can't; it’s not advisable at all, it sounds like a common English-as-a-foreign language error.

*Since* has to have a specific time reference. *Two months ago* is such a reference, but a reader might initially be confused by seeing *since* followed by *two months*, which would normally be preceded by *for*. The correct alternatives are:

> *I`ve been working here for two months*

or

> *I started working here two months ago.*

Comment: Whatever reference you and @Barrie are using, you really ought to cite it.

Comment: No reference. I just copied most of Barry's answer for effect. I agree with absolutely everything he said except for the first two words.